# What is the marginal probabilities formula used in CRF++?

Tags: machine-learning

CRF++ says it can:

"Can output marginal probabilities for all candidates" on its page: http://crfpp.sourceforge.net/

But what's the notation of the formula that's used to find these probabilities, in  conditional random fields?

Someone told me it's not simply `p(a|b)`, because conditional random fields use context from adjacent observations.

What exactly are these marginal probabilities?

Answer (score 1):

The conditional probability is just `p(y|x)` where `y` is a sequence of labels and `x` is the associated observed sequence.

The expression for this probability is just the softmax function `\exp( a_i ) / \sum_{i'} \exp ( a_{i'})`.

For a CRF, `a_i` is a function of the label sequence `a_i = w \cdot \phi(x,y)`, where `\phi(x,y)` is a feature vector derived from a sequence and its labels.

This means that the sum in the denominator is over the **exponential** number of possible labels, `\mathcal{Y}`:

```
\sum_{y' \in \mathcal{Y}} \exp ( w \cdot \phi(x,y) )
```